# Connect R to remote mongoDB with rmongodb

Tags: r, mongodb, rmongodb

I'm trying to connect remotely to mongoDB from R: 
The credentials code to connect looks like this.

```
library(rmongodb)
mongo <- mongo.create(host="111.222.333.444", name='', username="username",
                      password="password", db="dbname",
                      timeout = 10L)
```

MongoDB is installed locally, and the misterious side of the question is that the connection works using the command line tool. The call looks like this:

```
mongo host:port/dbname -u username -p password
MongoDB shell version: 3.2.1
connecting to: ...
```

I've also tried `RMongo` but didn't work either. Using OSX and R version 3.2.0.

Comment: What is the exact error?

Comment: Authentication failed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`rmongodb` doesn't support SCRAM-SHA-1 authentication. see https://github.com/mongosoup/rmongodb/issues/77. Check [mongolite](https://github.com/jeroenooms/mongolite) package.