# Power BI and MongoDB - What is the best setup?

Tags: mongodb, powerbi

Currently i have a database with almost 50kk record and an collection with almost 20kk that i need to connect with PowerBI, I tried using the MongoDB BI Connector, but it is impossible slow, are anything I can do to speed things up? Or should i move to something more robust to help my BI Team?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Need to identify the performance bottle neck in detail.

1. If data import is slow, then Extract the data from Mongo DB into a file. (as the data volume that you specified seems to be low - in thousands). Then import the file into Power BI model.
2. If the slicing and dicing is slower after data import into PowerBI, then tuning the model is required.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Anything going through ODBC (I am guessing that's what you are using), is going to be slow. One way to do this is to use r from Power BI to get the data from MongoDB. The following link gives details about how you can connect to MongoDB from r:

[Connect R to remote mongoDB with rmongodb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35028809/connect-r-to-remote-mongodb-with-rmongodb)

Once your query is ready, you can choose "R Script" from the "Get data" window to use the r query. Hope this helps.